# I want to take permission of storage and media access on click of button in my app java but app got crashed

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Android image taking app crashed on clicking button. I want to take permission of storage and media access on click of button in my app through java and when click on allow it give permission there is a button to take image but when I click on it app got crashed and when I restart the app and then click on button app didn't crashed.

I am expecting that my app will run well at once after giving permission and didn't got crashed on clicking button.

Comment: Well, my knee hurts and I don't want that to happen. ... Seriously, we need much more information like code, stack traces etc. to help. You might want to read [ask] and then [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.